# React: can't get state from child to parent

Tags: reactjs

I have a `Login` component:

```
var React = require('react');
var LoginForm = require('./LoginForm');


    class Login extends React.Component {

        constructor (props) {
            super(props)

            // Bind the this context to the handler function
            this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);

            // Set some state
            this.state = {
                username: '',
                password: '',
                token: ''
            };
        }

        handler(data) {
            this.setState(data);
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div className="login-container">
                    <div className="outer">
                        <div className="middle">
                            <div className="inner">
                                <LoginForm loginHandler={this.handler}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    module.exports = Login;
```

and a `LoginForm` one:

```
var React = require('react');
import axios from 'axios';

class LoginForm extends React.Component {

    handleLoginClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/";
        var payload={
            "email": "jermaine71@yahoo.com",
            "password": "thePassword"
        };
        axios.post(apiBaseUrl, payload)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);

                var data = {
                    username: 'jermaine71@yahoo.com',
                    password: 'thePassword',
                }

                this.props.loginHandler(data) . // <-- FAILS HERE. this is undefined

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                alert('NO');
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Email Address" required="" />
                <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required=""/>
                <p></p>
                <button onClick={(event) => this.handleLoginClick(event)} className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = LoginForm;
```

I know the actual axios function should be done elsewhere, but my question is different: I can't seem to be able to get the username, password and token information to the parent. The function fails at the point shown above where this is undefined and no access to the handler from the child is available. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is undefined? `data` in `LoginForm` or the `loginHandler` function?

Comment: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined. The this of this.props is undefined in LoginForm

Comment: In `"email": "jermaine71@yahoo.com",//this.state.username`, `this` refers to your `LoginForm` which does not have defined state.

Comment: I know. that's a comment I removed. using direct values for this test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using ES6, then you need to use a fat arrow function in your `.then` in the `handleLoginClick` function.

```
axios.post(apiBaseUrl, payload)
.then( response => {
    var data = {
        username: 'jermaine71@yahoo.com',
        password: 'thePassword',
    };
    this.props.loginHandler(data);
})
.catch( error => {
    alert('NO');
    console.log(error);
});
```

Alternatively, you can pass in a component function that is already bound to `this`:

```
handleClickResponse(response) {
    var data = {
        username: 'jermaine71@yahoo.com',
        password: 'thePassword',
    };
    this.props.loginHandler(data);
}
handleLoginClick(){
   ...
    axios.post(apiBaseUrl, payload)
    .then(response => this.handleClickResponse(response))
    .catch( error => {
        alert('NO');
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: And that also takes care of the binding... yes. that worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you must bind your anonymous promise function

```
axios.post(apiBaseUrl, payload)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);

            var data = {
                username: 'jermaine71@yahoo.com',
                password: 'thePassword',
            }

            this.props.loginHandler(data) . // <-- FAILS HERE. this is undefined

        }.bind(this))  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE
        .catch(function (error) {
            alert('NO');
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: Chase DeAnda answer is valid too imho

Comment: Yes as => will take care of the biding. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`props` is `undefined` because when the context of `this` in the axios `.then` call is not referencing the `this` you expect.

Inside `handleLoginClick` do this so you can still access the `this`:

```
handleLoginClick(event) {
    var here = this

    //... then inside the `then`

    axios.post(apiBaseUrl, payload)
        .then(function (response) {
            //...
            here.props.loginHandler(data)
        })
```

Or use the fat arrow function like so:

```
.then(response => {
    this.props.loginHandler(data)
})
```